# How to hide SharePoint Content Query webpart when empty?

Tags: sharepoint

How to hide SharePoint Content Query web part when empty? Is there any web part property for hiding the Content Query web part.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide the details on what have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried to look through the web property, but no option to hide if no item.

Comment: Content Search webpart has a direct option to hide items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below Jquery code and it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elements = $('.cbq-layout-main');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if ((elements[i].innerText || elements[i].textContent) === '') {
        elements[i].parentNode.parentNode.firstElementChild.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
});
</script>
```